# Error not thrown as expected in JavaScript simple calculator app

Tags: javascript, exception, throw

I'm creating a simple calculator app for homework using JavaScript.
I need to validate that the input numbers will be exactly two, and that they will be numbers, otherwise I should throw an error.

If we look at the addition operation only, my original code was

```
function add(number1, number2) {
  if (arguments.length !== 2) {
    throw new Error('Please supply two numbers');
  }
  if (!Number.isFinite(number1) || !Number.isFinite(number2)) {
    throw new Error('Only numbers are allowed');
  }
  return number1 + number2;
}
```

It works when I test it using `console.log`. But I didn't want to repeat myself with the validations so I created a function encapsulating these two checks, and then I'll just call that function in my operations.
But this seems to break my error throwing and I don't understand why.

```
function inputValidation(number1, number2) {
  if (arguments.length !== 2) {
    throw new Error('Please supply two numbers');
  }
  if (!Number.isFinite(number1) || !Number.isFinite(number2)) {
    throw new Error('Only numbers are allowed');
  }
}

function add(number1, number2) {
  inputValidation(number1, number2);
  return number1 + number2;
}
```

The `Number.isFinite` continues to work, but the arguments length seems to break and I don't understand why. My test gives me the below error:

```
1) error is thrown if not exactly two arguments
       should throw Please supply two numbers:
     AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing expected exception (Error).
```

What am I missing?
Thank you

Comment: Your code always passes two arguments to `inputValidation()`, regardless of how many arguments were passed to `add()`.

Comment: @Pointy but isn't it transferable to the next function like the `Number.isFinite` works in this case?

Comment: ?? Transferrable? I don't know what you mean, but it is plain as day that your code always passes two arguments to `inputValidation()`.

Comment: In this particular case, checking that the arguments are both numbers is really all you have to do. If an argument is not passed, then in the function that parameter variable will be `undefined`, and `undefined` is not a number.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for your quick replies. In Java I used to make such functions as separate in order to validate inputs. My understanding is that when I call the `inputValidation` function it says: I'll take `number1` and `number2` from the `add` function and pass them into the `inputValidation` function. Then it performs the two checks and throws the errors if the conditions are met. But the two checks seem to behave differently when called from the `add` function, why is that?

Comment: @Pointy I thought that even if my function has two parameters, in JavaScript you can pass more than two arguments. With the above approach, even if I pass three parameters in the `add` function, it always depends how many I pass in my `inputValidation` function if I will get an error or not. What would be the correct approach then? How do I make sure that I always get ONLY two arguments in my functions? Does it mean I need to write the same code in each operation (add, subtr, divide, multiply) bcs otherwise I won't catch the wrong number of inputs?

Comment: Yes. In JavaScript, as you have noted, a function can be passed any number of arguments without regard to the parameters listed in the function definition. If you really want to count the parameters, you have to do it with your own code, and in every function where that is important. Most libraries in the JavaScript world do not do that.

Answer (score 2):

Your add function is passing 2 arguments to inputValidation. In case the add function didn't get number1 or number2 as argument, it uses undefined as argument.

So in that case, `arguments.length !== 2` is always false.
A better option is to check if one of the 2 arguments is not equal to undefined `if (!(number1 && number2))`

See example here on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7ps8x9h/)

You can also consider only performing the 2nd check, namely whether the arguments are both numbers. You could change the error message to 'enter 2 numbers'.